# Google Analytics tracking code doesn't record downloads in RealTime

Tags: pdf, events, google-analytics, real-time, tracking

I have added a snippet of javascript to my pdf download links in order to track downloads. When I watch RealTime Events from the GA dashboard, I don't see any activity when I click on a download link. My links have the following code:

```
<a class='non-html' href='pdf/XXXX_2017_meeting_program.pdf' onclick=”var that=this;_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’,’Download’,’PDF’,this.href]);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;”>2017: 18th Annual Symposium, Chicago, IL, USA</a>
```

Is the link properly formed and am I looking in the correct place to observe event activity in real time?

**Follow-Up:** OK, I've kept it simple, just the command "event" and 1 parameter, "Download". I still don't see any activity. I have the most current gtag:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXX-XX'></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX--XX');
</script>`
```

and the link codes is as follows:

```
<a class='non-html' href='pdf/XXXX_2017_meeting_program.pdf'  onclick = 'gtag ('event', 'Download');' >2017: 18th Annual Symposium, Chicago, IL, USA</a>
```

Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: *Suggestion:* ga.js is a legacy library. If you are starting a new implementation, we recommend you use the latest version of this library, analytics.js.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which library you use - analytics.js or gtag.js, correct your code:

```
onclick ="ga('send', 'event', <category>, <action>, <label>, <value>);"
```

or

```
 onclick = "gtag('event', <action>, {'event_category': <category>,'event_label': <label>,'value': <value>});"
```

To see event in real time use report *Real Time - Events*.